# What tools exist to find frequencies of searches

Tags: api, search, seo

I'm new to seo, so please excuse what may be a very basic question.

I want to count (or estimate) the number of times that a given search phrase has been searched within a particular time period.  Are there any API's out there for this?  Does Google (or any other relevant search engine) release this information?

Any helpful links are greatly appreciated.

I'll be using Java, though I doubt that makes much difference.

Comment: Please indicate why this question is inappropriate, if you feel the need to vote to close.

Comment: I'm not one of them, but there seem to be many people on here that feel SEO questions are inappropriate for SO, regardless of the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the WordTracker API might be the best took for programmatically finding search data.

http://www.wordtracker.com/api/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any API for it, but you can use [Google Insights for Search](http://www.google.com/insights/search/)

Answer (score 0):

I use [link text](https://adwords.google.com/select/KeywordToolExternal)

it also presents the volume for every search

Answer (score -1):

Check out [this improv API to Google Trends](http://www.juiceanalytics.com/openjuice/programmatic-google-trends-api/) which helps you export data.